# Build numpy array with multiple custom index ranges without explicit loop

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, vectorization

In Numpy, is there a pythonic way to create array3 with custom ranges from array1 and array2 without a loop? The straightforward solution of iterating over the ranges works but since my arrays run into millions of items, I am looking for a more efficient solution (maybe syntactic sugar too).

For ex.,

```
array1 = np.array([10, 65, 200]) 
array2 = np.array([14, 70, 204])
array3 = np.concatenate([np.arange(array1[i], array2[i]) for i in
                         np.arange(0,len(array1))])

print array3
```

result: `[10,11,12,13,65,66,67,68,69,200,201,202,203]`.

Comment: If it works, is clear, and is fast *enough*, it is 'pythonic'.  `numpy-onic` requires eliminating the explicit loop.  :)

Comment: Another friendly reminder query : Did any of the solutions work for you?

Comment: @Divakar Sorry for the late response. All responses are nice and ultimately I used your solution. Very elegant I must say and thank you for sharing your thought process. The data is at work and I have been on vacation until today. I wanted to collect all the functions here to run on my data to check performance and thus didn't respond yet.

Comment: @snowmonkey Ah no worries! And glad to hear back from you, finally! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Prospective Approach

I will go backwards on how to approach this problem.

Take the sample listed in the question. We have -

```
array1 = np.array([10, 65, 200])
array2 = np.array([14, 70, 204])
```

Now, look at the desired result -

```
result: [10,11,12,13,65,66,67,68,69,200,201,202,203]
```

Let's calculate the group lengths, as we would be needing those to explain the solution approach next.

```
In [58]: lens = array2 - array1

In [59]: lens
Out[59]: array([4, 5, 4])
```

The idea is to use `1`'s initialized array, which when cumumlative summed across the entire length would give us the desired result.
This cumumlative summation would be the last step to our solution.
Why `1`'s initialized? Well, because we have an array that increasing in steps of `1`'s except at specific places where we have shifts
corresponding to new groups coming in.

Now, since `cumsum` would be the last step, so the step before it should give us something like -

```
array([ 10,   1,   1,   1,  52,   1,   1,   1,   1, 131,   1,   1,   1])
```

As discussed before, it's `1`'s filled with `[10,52,131]` at specific places. That `10` seems to be coming in from the first element in `array1`, but what about the rest?
The second one `52` came in as `65-13` (looking at the `result`) and in it `13` came in the group that started with `10` and ran because of the length of
the first group `4`. So, if we do `65 - 10 - 4`, we will get `51` and then add `1` to accomodate for boundary stop, we would have `52`, which is the
desired shifting value. Similarly, we would get `131`.

Thus, those `shifting-values` could be computed, like so -

```
In [62]: np.diff(array1) - lens[:-1]+1
Out[62]: array([ 52, 131])
```

Next up, to get those `shifting-places` where such shifts occur, we can simply do cumulative summation on the group lengths -

```
In [65]: lens[:-1].cumsum()
Out[65]: array([4, 9])
```

For completeness, we need to pre-append `0` with the array of `shifting-places` and `array1[0]` for `shifting-values`.

So, we are set to present our approach in a step-by-step format!

---

### Putting back the pieces

1] Get lengths of each group :

```
lens = array2 - array1
```

2] Get indices at which shifts occur and values to be put in `1`'s initialized array :

```
shift_idx = np.hstack((0,lens[:-1].cumsum()))
shift_vals = np.hstack((array1[0],np.diff(array1) - lens[:-1]+1))
```

3] Setup `1`'s initialized ID array for inserting those values at those indices listed in the step before :

```
id_arr = np.ones(lens.sum(),dtype=array1.dtype)
id_arr[shift_idx] = shift_vals
```

4] Finally do cumulative summation on the ID array :

```
output = id_arr.cumsum()
```

Listed in a function format, we would have -

```
def using_ones_cumsum(array1, array2):
    lens = array2 - array1
    shift_idx = np.hstack((0,lens[:-1].cumsum()))
    shift_vals = np.hstack((array1[0],np.diff(array1) - lens[:-1]+1))
    id_arr = np.ones(lens.sum(),dtype=array1.dtype)
    id_arr[shift_idx] = shift_vals
    return id_arr.cumsum()
```

And it works on overlapping ranges too!

```
In [67]: array1 = np.array([10, 11, 200]) 
    ...: array2 = np.array([14, 18, 204])
    ...: 

In [68]: using_ones_cumsum(array1, array2)
Out[68]: 
array([ 10,  11,  12,  13,  11,  12,  13,  14,  15,  16,  17, 200, 201,
       202, 203])
```

---

**Runtime test**

Let's time the proposed approach against the other vectorized approach in [`@unutbu's flatnonzero based solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37624918/3293881), which already proved to be much better than the loopy approach -

```
In [38]: array1, array2 = (np.random.choice(range(1, 11), size=10**4, replace=True)
    ...:                   .cumsum().reshape(2, -1, order='F'))

In [39]: %timeit using_flatnonzero(array1, array2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 889 µs per loop

In [40]: %timeit using_ones_cumsum(array1, array2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 235 µs per loop
```

---

### Improvement!

Now, codewise NumPy doesn't like appending. So, those `np.hstack` calls could be avoided for a slightly improved version as listed below -

```
def get_ranges_arr(starts,ends):
    counts = ends - starts
    counts_csum = counts.cumsum()
    id_arr = np.ones(counts_csum[-1],dtype=int)
    id_arr[0] = starts[0]
    id_arr[counts_csum[:-1]] = starts[1:] - ends[:-1] + 1
    return id_arr.cumsum()
```

Let's time it against our original approach -

```
In [151]: array1,array2 = (np.random.choice(range(1, 11),size=10**4, replace=True)\
     ...:                                      .cumsum().reshape(2, -1, order='F'))

In [152]: %timeit using_ones_cumsum(array1, array2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 276 µs per loop

In [153]: %timeit get_ranges_arr(array1, array2)
10000 loops, best of 3: 193 µs per loop
```

So, we have a **`30%`** performance boost there!

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the ranges do not overlap, you could build a mask which is nonzero where the index is between the ranges specified by `array1` and `array2` and then use `np.flatnonzero` to obtain an array of indices -- the desired `array3`:

```
import numpy as np

array1 = np.array([10, 65, 200]) 
array2 = np.array([14, 70, 204])

first, last = array1.min(), array2.max()
array3 = np.zeros(last-first+1, dtype='i1')
array3[array1-first] = 1
array3[array2-first] = -1
array3 = np.flatnonzero(array3.cumsum())+first
print(array3)
```

yields

```
[ 10  11  12  13  65  66  67  68  69 200 201 202 203]
```

---

For large `len(array1)`, `using_flatnonzero` can be significantly faster than `using_loop`:

```
def using_flatnonzero(array1, array2):
    first, last = array1.min(), array2.max()
    array3 = np.zeros(last-first+1, dtype='i1')
    array3[array1-first] = 1
    array3[array2-first] = -1
    return np.flatnonzero(array3.cumsum())+first

def using_loop(array1, array2):
    return np.concatenate([np.arange(array1[i], array2[i]) for i in
                           np.arange(0,len(array1))])


array1, array2 = (np.random.choice(range(1, 11), size=10**4, replace=True)
                  .cumsum().reshape(2, -1, order='F'))


assert np.allclose(using_flatnonzero(array1, array2), using_loop(array1, array2))
```

---

```
In [260]: %timeit using_loop(array1, array2)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.36 ms per loop

In [261]: %timeit using_flatnonzero(array1, array2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 564 µs per loop
```

---

If the ranges overlap, then `using_loop` will return an `array3` which contains duplicates. `using_flatnonzero` returns an array with no duplicates.

---

**Explanation**: Let's look at a small example with

```
array1 = np.array([10, 65, 200]) 
array2 = np.array([14, 70, 204])
```

The objective is to build an array which looks like `goal`, below. The 1's are located at index values `[ 10,  11,  12,  13,  65,  66,  67,  68,  69, 200, 201, 202, 203]` (i.e. `array3`):

```
In [306]: goal
Out[306]: 
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int8)
```

Once we have the `goal` array, `array3` can be obtained with a call to `np.flatnonzero`:

```
In [307]: np.flatnonzero(goal)
Out[307]: array([ 10,  11,  12,  13,  65,  66,  67,  68,  69, 200, 201, 202, 203])
```

`goal` has the same length as `array2.max()`:

```
In [308]: array2.max()
Out[308]: 204

In [309]: goal.shape
Out[309]: (204,)
```

So we can begin by allocating

```
goal = np.zeros(array2.max()+1, dtype='i1')
```

and then filling in 1's at the index locations given by `array1` and -1's at the indices given by `array2`:

```
In [311]: goal[array1] = 1
In [312]: goal[array2] = -1
In [313]: goal
Out[313]: 
array([ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,
        0,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,
       -1], dtype=int8)
```

Now applying `cumsum` (the cumulative sum) produces the desired `goal` array:

```
In [314]: goal = goal.cumsum(); goal
Out[314]: 
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0])

In [315]: np.flatnonzero(goal)
Out[315]: array([ 10,  11,  12,  13,  65,  66,  67,  68,  69, 200, 201, 202, 203])
```

That's the main idea behind `using_flatnonzero`. The subtraction of `first` was simply to save a bit of memory.

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach combining [vectorize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) and [concatenate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

**Implementation**:

```
import numpy as np

array1, array2 = np.array([10, 65, 200]), np.array([14, 70, 204])

ranges = np.vectorize(lambda a, b: np.arange(a, b), otypes=[np.ndarray])
result = np.concatenate(ranges(array1, array2), axis=0)

print result
# [ 10  11  12  13  65  66  67  68  69 200 201 202 203]
```

---

**Performance**:

```
%timeit np.concatenate(ranges(array1, array2), axis=0)
```

> 100000 loops, best of 3: 13.9 µs per loop

Comment: I expect `vectorize` will have a modest speed improvement over a list concatenation, maybe 20%.  It still iterates.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
In [440]: np.r_[10:14,65:70,200:204]
Out[440]: array([ 10,  11,  12,  13,  65,  66,  67,  68,  69, 200, 201, 202, 203])
```

or generalizing:

```
In [454]: np.r_[tuple([slice(i,j) for i,j in zip(array1,array2)])]
Out[454]: array([ 10,  11,  12,  13,  65,  66,  67,  68,  69, 200, 201, 202, 203])
```

Though this does involve a double loop, the explicit one to generate the slices and one inside `r_` to convert the slices to `arange`.

```
    for k in range(len(key)):
        scalar = False
        if isinstance(key[k], slice):
            step = key[k].step
            start = key[k].start
                ...
                newobj = _nx.arange(start, stop, step)
```

I mention this because it shows that `numpy` developers consider your kind  of iteration normal.

I expect that @unutbu's cleaver, if somewhat obtuse (I haven't figured out what it is doing yet), solution is your best chance of speed. `cumsum` is a good tool when you need to work with ranges than can vary in length.  It probably gains most when the working with many small ranges.  I don't think it works with overlapping ranges.

================

`np.vectorize` uses `np.frompyfunc`.  So this iteration can also be expressed with:

```
In [467]: f=np.frompyfunc(lambda x,y: np.arange(x,y), 2,1)

In [468]: f(array1,array2)
Out[468]: 
array([array([10, 11, 12, 13]), array([65, 66, 67, 68, 69]),
       array([200, 201, 202, 203])], dtype=object)

In [469]: timeit np.concatenate(f(array1,array2))
100000 loops, best of 3: 17 µs per loop

In [470]: timeit np.r_[tuple([slice(i,j) for i,j in zip(array1,array2)])]
10000 loops, best of 3: 65.7 µs per loop
```

With @Darius's `vectorize` solution:

```
In [474]: timeit result = np.concatenate(ranges(array1, array2), axis=0)
10000 loops, best of 3: 52 µs per loop
```

`vectorize` must be doing some extra work to allow more powerful use of broadcasting.  Relative speeds may shift if `array1` is much larger.

@unutbu's solution isn't special with this small `array1`.

```
In [478]: timeit using_flatnonzero(array1,array2)
10000 loops, best of 3: 57.3 µs per loop
```

The OP solution, iterative without my `r_` middle man is good

```
In [483]: timeit array3 = np.concatenate([np.arange(array1[i], array2[i]) for i in np.arange(0,len(array1))])
10000 loops, best of 3: 24.8 µs per loop
```

It's often the case that with a small number of loops, a list comprehension is faster than fancier `numpy` operations.

For @unutbu's larger test case, my timings are consistent with his - with a 17x speed up.

===================

For the small sample arrays, @Divakar's solution is slower, but for the large ones 3x faster than @unutbu's.  So it has more of a setup cost, but scales slower.

Comment: I like your comparisons.