# Calculate the row average of selected columns

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I have a csv file:

```
#col1 #col2 ... #col253
33,    123, ...    99
19,    409, ...    24
34,    239, ...    60
...    ...  ...    ..
```

and a dictionary whose values store the start and end index of selected columns:

```
d = {
    'win': [(11, 55), (194, 233)],
    'lose': [(72, 111), (133, 172)],
    'neut': [(0, 10), (51, 71), (112, 132), (173, 193)]
    }
```

My goal is to calculate averages per row for all the selected columns of a certain key in the dictionary.

For example, for the `'win'` block of the first row, select the `11, 12, ...55, 194, 195,...233` columns and calculate the average.

What I am using now:

```
x = np.loadtxt('filename.csv', delimiter=',')
for line in x:
    selected = [line[start:end + 1] for (start, end) in d['win']]
    ...
```

`selected` will be `[array([39, 12, 94,...]), array([3, 4, ...])]` which can not be passed to `np.mean()`.

So arrays in the list should be combined to one, which I don't know how to do elegantly, or iteratively add all numbers and then take the average, which I think is ugly.

---

**Edited:**

An ugly method could be:

```
average = sum(map(sum, selected)) / sum(map(len, selected))
```

Comment: Are you looking for the total mean over every row, or the mean per row? From your example it looks like the means for each row separately.

Comment: @IljaEverilä For each row, sorry for the bad description.

Answer (score 2):

Numpy arrays support [rich indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html), so this can be achieved for example by slicing over all the rows and passing a list of columns to select.

To calculate for each row separately you can pass the `axis` (or axes) along which the means are computed as an argument to [`mean()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html):

```
columns = np.hstack(tuple(np.arange(a, b + 1) for a, b in d['win']))
row_means = x[:, columns].mean(axis=1)
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I am looking for,  thank you very much, bro!

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of columns that covers all those *interval-ed* ranges in a vectorized manner using [`this other solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37626057/3293881). Then, index into the columns of input array, `x` with those and calculate the average along the second axis `(axis=1)`.

Let me list out the vectorized function to create an array of such *interval-ed* ranges again here for the convenience of readers -

```
def using_ones_cumsum_v2(array1, array2):
    lens = array2 - array1
    id_arr = np.ones(lens.sum(),dtype=array1.dtype)
    id_arr[lens[:-1].cumsum()] = np.diff(array1) - lens[:-1]+1
    id_arr[0] = array1[0]
    return id_arr.cumsum()
```

With it, we would have the averages for the `win` key, like so -

```
d_win = np.array(d['win'])
out_win = x[:,using_ones_cumsum_v2(d_win[:,0],d_win[:,1]+1)].mean(1)
```

Sample run to demonstrate the usage of `using_ones_cumsum_v2` to create *interval-ed* ranges -

```
In [24]: d = {
    ...:     'win': [(1, 3), (5, 8)],
    ...:     'lose': [(2, 5), (7, 8)],
    ...:     'neut': [(0, 1), (4, 7), (8, 9)]
    ...:     }

In [25]: d_win = np.array(d['win'])

In [26]: d_win
Out[26]: 
array([[1, 3],
       [5, 8]])

In [27]: using_ones_cumsum_v2(d_win[:,0],d_win[:,1]+1)
Out[27]: array([1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```