# numpy arange with specific gaps

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Is there a cleaner and nicer way in python3.x to do

```
a = np.arange(1,4)
b = np.arange(5,10)
c = np.concatenate((a,b))
```

? So the result is `c = [1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10]`
Please note, that the chosen numbers in this example are arbitrary!

Comment: Another duplicate with timings, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624798/build-numpy-array-with-multiple-custom-index-ranges-without-explicit-loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.delete` seems a bit faster than `np.r_`:

```
>>> from timeit import repeat
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> min(repeat('np.r_[1:4, 5:10]', globals=globals(), number=100000))
1.2129063629545271
>>> min(repeat('np.delete(np.arange(1, 10), 4)', globals=globals(), number=100000))
0.6783314400818199
```

... but not nearly as fast as OP's concatenation

```
>>> min(repeat('np.concatenate((np.arange(1, 4), np.arange(5, 10)))', globals=globals(), number=100000))
0.1798924310132861
```

Comment: ironic, the solution I thought to be the worst performs the best

Comment: `r_` is pretty, but has a fair amount of overhead; it's really syntactic sugar.  Internally it uses `arange` and `concatenate`.  More on `r_` here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37743843/python-why-use-numpy-r-instead-of-concatenate/37751518#37751518

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`numpy.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) object.

```
c = np.r_[1:4, 5:10]
```

I feel like this might have been asked before

Answer (score 1):

Not really.  Using a little information theory ...

You have two independent ideas here: a sequence and exclusions.  Sure, you could concoct a polynomial that exhibits those values at equal intervals, but that would not be simpler.

This reduces fairly easily to one of two solutions: concatenate the individual contiguous sequences (your posting), or construct the full range, but remove the exclusions before use.  You can do either with shorter notation, but nothing that is inherently "nicer" in all respects.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your concrete usecase, sth like this could also solve your issue:

```
np.array([ x + (x>3) for x in range(1,9) ])
```

Or in pure numpy:

```
a = np.arange(1, 9)
a += (a>3)  # or similar
```

But I mention this only for completeness's sake.  I'd be hard pressed to think up a case where this would be a good solution.  Certainly not before some weird and hard optimization step.

But keep in mind that this approach is way more general and could also be used with more complex calculations than just `(a>3)`.