# Numpy 2D indexing of a 1D array with known min, max indices

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 1D numpy array of False booleans, and a 2D numpy array containing the min,max indices of values in the first array to change to True.

An example:

```
my_data = numpy.zeros((10,), dtype=bool)
inds2true = numpy.array([[1, 3], [8, 9]])
```

And I want the following result:

```
out = numpy.array([False, True, True, True, False,  False,  False,  False, True, True])
```

How is this possible in Python with Numpy?

Edit: I would like this to be performed in one step (i.e. no looping).

Comment: It appears to be not an easy task in numpy. [There is a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624798/build-numpy-array-with-multiple-custom-index-ranges-without-explicit-loop)

Comment: One way or other you have to iterate through the `inds2true`, whether applying the pairs as slices, or turning them into one array of indices.  So it's possible, but not mindlessly simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one rule-breaking hack:

```
my_data[inds2true] = True
my_data = np.cumsum(my_data) % 2 == 1
my_data
>>> array([False,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False])
```

The most common practise is to change indices within `np.arange([1, 3])` and `np.arange([8, 9])`, not including 3 or 9. If you still want to include them, do in addition: `my_data[inds2true[:, 1]] = True`

If you're looking for other options to do it in one go, the most probably it will include `np.cumsum` tricks.

Comment: Very smart. What do you mean by "rule-breaking"?

Comment: Well, `inds2true` are usually 1-D indices of 1-D array. In the second scenario, you should use multiple arrays as a case of [Advanced Indexing](https://towardsdatascience.com/numpy-indexing-explained-c376abb2440d). I'm not used to use 2-D indexing of 1-D array like this: `my_data[inds2true]`. I'd rather do: `my_data[inds2true.ravel()]`

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np
my_data = np.zeros((10,), dtype=bool)
inds2true = np.array([[1, 3], [8, 9]])
indeces = []
for ix_range in inds2true:
    indeces += list(range(ix_range[0], ix_range[1] + 1))
my_data[indeces] = True
```